# email-inline.css in Magento Transactional emails not working

Tags: css, email, magento, magento-1.9, transactional-email

I have a question regarding Magento transactional emails.
The problem is with email-inline.css:

```
 {{inlinecss file=“email-inline.css“}}
```

They just do not work.
Everything is alright when I sent emails locally but when I push the Code and send from live shop, they don't work.
I have checked everything and I have no clue what can be the problem.

Have anyone maybe the same problem and maybe a solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

External css file doesn't work in most email provider, because most webmail clients will block links to external stylesheets for security considerations.

You have to write the css inline, like `<h1 style="color: #1c70db;">Title</h3>`, that works for me.

Some css grammar may not work in some email clients, so you have to test the email as many different email clients as you can possibly get access to.

Comment: But why that inline css file works when I sent from my local project?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the permissions for the file are not set correctly. I had similar issue.

> email-inline.css